# Change CSS when element is over a certain div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navbar with `poisition: fixed`. Sometimes my logo isn't visible anymore because it has the same color as the `div` behind it. I was wondering if in JavaScript I could change the CSS (add a filter or whatever) whenever the logo is over that certain `div`.

Comment: you can change the color of the navbar, It is not recommended to have a navbar and brand logo having the same color or color theme.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascripts intersection observer api.
It enables you to check if an element is in the viewport and where.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API